# Tranverse electromagnetic waves

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation, waves

TEM waves do not exist in waveguide. Is this the correct explanation- Both curl and divergence of TEM are zero inside the waveguide and because of the boundary conditions (electric field zero at every point of a hollow conductor), the only solution possible is zero i.e. trivial?

Answer (score 2):

TEM waves ***do*** exist in multi-conductor waveguides such as coaxial guides, in fact they exist in any homogeneous waveguide with more than one conductor. There are no *propagating* TEM, TE or TM modes if the cross section is inhomogeneous but at cutoff frequency the hybrid modes degenerate to the respective transversal modes.